# android google map API problems

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Right, I understand this question has been answered on many places, And yet I don't get what problem I have, I have recently moved to android application and trying to use map on my app.

I exactly followed these links:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNlleczyPjs

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#install_and_configure_the_google_play_services_sdk

So my question is, what else could I have done wrong. I just don't get it...

My feeling is that my key is not registered properly but when I created new key I provided following information:

```
Android apps:   
9D:7C:<THIS BIT IS SECRET>84:0F;com.example.myapp
```

**EXTRA INFORMATION**

here is the error log:

```
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:308)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at com.example.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:8)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    ... 11 more
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:584)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:552)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4849)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    ... 20 more
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:574)
11-28 11:09:59.471: E/AndroidRuntime(31683):    ... 23 more
11-28 11:09:59.511: D/dalvikvm(31683): GC_CONCURRENT freed 190K, 9% free 12391K/13575K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 36ms
```

here is the code :

```
package com.example.myapp;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Here is the androidManifext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk  android:minSdkVersion="8"   android:targetSdkVersion="21" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
                <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXwKo"/>
                <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and here is main_activity.xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

**IT WORKED**
Jesus , it just started working out of no where. eclipse just got stock it took me about 10min to get eclipse working. now it just started to work and so is the app. I have no idea what happened and no idea why it was bugging me. basically all I can say is probably it takes few hours for an api key to get to work.

Comment: reference `google_play_services_lib` in your project....

Comment: @MD I did import (with copy files into the project) then added it to the project from properties->android>add library

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what is causing problems but it looks odd to me that your main_activity.xml has no Layout container, e.g. LinearLayout, RelativeLayout..

Could your try making main_activity.xml look like this and see what happens:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Alternatively I would suggest trying the tutorial from vogella http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html it worked perfectly for me.

Reading the error log once more, I wonder if you have added the support library to your project. In eclipse it goes like: Rightclick project -> Android tools -> Add Support Library...

Comment: mate, it just ended up working by its own. I have no idea why and how. I basically didn't change anything on my code.

Answer (score 0):

plz add this permissions then only it works

```
<permission
        android:name="<your package name>.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="<your package name>.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

Comment: I only added 5 permissions, I haven't added the READ_GSERVICES

Comment: k please add above permission and try to run

Comment: mate, it just ended up working by its own. I have no idea why and how. I basically didn't change anything on my code.

Comment: @nafas I bet it is the usual situation where a clean of the project resolves issues, my guess is that along the way, the project has been cleaned or at least updated in the workspace. Great it is working ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using...

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

It works fine for me

Comment: mate, it just ended up working by its own. I have no idea why and how. I basically didn't change anything on my code.

Comment: @Mr.Blueskies why repeat an answer that has already been made? Also fill_parent is deprecated and the LinearLayout is missing a close tag at the bottom.